# Change table cell color depending on its value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
 $(".yourtableclassname tr:not(:first)").each(function() { 


}
```

I am using the above to iterate through all the rows in table excluding the first row because those are column titles.  Then depending on some of the column value, I set the background color of that row.

This works great if I have just one table.  But if I have two tables with the same class name, it treats the second table's rows as rows of the first table. So the second table's row header's background colors get set.

Anyway, I can fix that?  I may have several tables on the form, so I don't want to use the id.

--example code --

```
$(".Grid tr:not(:first)").each(function() { 

        var nameofField = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").html();            

        if(nameofField != ""){

            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('Red').removeClass('Blue');
        }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code that actually does the color change?

Comment: If you use `$(this)` to refer to the current row, it should access the correct table.

Comment: example: $(this).closest('tr').addClass('Red').removeClass('Blue');

Comment: Please update the question with the full code, maybe even make a jsfiddle.

Comment: How about a jsFiddle.net example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for updating the colors looks correct. I'm guessing you described the problem incorrectly. The regular rows of the second table are probably getting updated correctly, the problem is just with the header row.

Try this selector:

```
$(".yourtableclassname tr:not(:first-child)")
```

This will skip the first row of each table. Your selector just skipped the first row of the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using `<th></th>` for your headers rows? That should solve it.

EDIT : If you can't use `<th></th>` use `$(".yourClassName").finds("tr:not(:first)")`. Should do the trick!

Comment: How will that solve the problem of updating the correct table? That just makes it unnecessary to use the `:not` selector.

Comment: It's a gridview and they don't output <th>'s

Comment: Because selecting $(".yourClass tr") returns an arrays of every rows under that class names ; every tables togethers. ':first' only refer the first item of the whole set. By using `<th>` every headers cells would be ignored.. But since alpha doesn't have on control over that, the answer is not appropriate.